# Priority Queue Not Comparing Correctly C++

Tags: c++, priority-queue

I am trying to create a priority queue consisting of pairs of int, char that gives me the pair with the greater int, but my code is not working properly. What am I doing wrong?

This is my comparator class:

```
class Compare
{
public:
    bool operator() (pair<int, char>a, pair<int, char>b)
    {
        return a.first > b.first;
    }
};
```

And this is my priority queue:

```
priority_queue<pair<int, char>, vector<pair<int, char>>, Compare> party;
```

But if I execute the code:

```
party.push(make_pair(2, 'A'));
party.push(make_pair(3, 'B'));
cout<<party.top().first;
```

It returns 2, instead of 3. How do I fix my implementation of the priority queue?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The same fix that Geordi La Forge would use: reverse the polarity:

```
bool operator() (const pair<int, char> &a, const pair<int, char> &b) const
{
    return a.first < b.first;
}
```

The comparison function always implements strict weak ordering, a.k.a. the logical `<` operation. But `priority_queue`, by definition, [gives you the largest value in the priority queue, first](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/priority_queue):

> ... provides constant time lookup of the largest (by default) element,

But the comparison function is still strict weak ordering:

> A Compare type providing a strict weak ordering.

Slightly counter-intuitive, but after a while, it does make sense...

P.S.: The comparison function should be a `const` function, and take `const` parameters, for efficiency, as shown in my example; but that's an additional detail.

Comment: As a matter of fact, the part about efficiency is controversial. If the function is inlined (as it should) it doesn't matter at all. And in unimaginable case where it wouldn't, passing by value would provide better performance, at least on 86_64.

Comment: Could you elaborate on how does it make sense? Do you mean all the default comparator is default to `std::less` so `priority_queue` takes less as default comparator but the behavior must provide the higheest priority?

Comment: @LouisGo - It makes sense because all other ordered associative containers ***and algorithms*** in the C++ library work the same way: `set` uses `<` (the default one or user-specified comparator); `map` uses `<` (ditto); `sort` uses `<` (ditto); `lower_bound` and `upper_bound` use `<` (ditto). Why should `priority_queue` be any different?

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I agree with you but you didn't state that in the answer so I was wondering if there is another reason.

Answer (score 2):

Priority queue expects Comparator to implement `less` - as any other container requiring weak ordering. However, it works by placing the bigger element on top. Since you effectively implemented `greater`, you reversed the queue, and now the smallest element goes on top.

To fix the problem, change your comparator to return lesser of the two elements.